# Adding default filter on tree view - OpenErp Custom module

Tags: python, xml, filter, odoo

I need to add a default filter, for the tree view of my module.

I saw some code example in openerp, like this one:

```
<filter
    string="Partner"
    icon="terp-partner"
    domain="[]"
    context="{'group_by':'partner_id'}"
    />
```

This one in the `purchase` module, grouped by `partner_id`, as an example.

Now, I have a custom module, which I need to have a 'default' filter when you click on its menu.

And this filter must show all the records which aren't 'expired', or that hasn't passed the actual date when I'm browsing the records in the module.

I have this field in my custom module:

```
'Fecha_de_Vence': fields.date(
    'Fecha de Vencimiento',
    required=True,
    select=True,
    ),
```

This is the field I need to take as a filter for all the records in this module.

Right now, in the 'advanced search' I can put for example `Fecha de Vencimiento` not more than `actual date`, well, I need to have this as a 'default' filter.

Anyone could shed some light in how to get this by default in openerp's xml view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a search view, and a context entry in act_window:

```
<record id="search_xxx_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">module.class.select</field>
    <field name="model">module.class</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="Search xxx">
            <field name="Fecha_de_Vence" string="Fecha de Vencimiento" filter_domain="[(1,'=',1)]"/>
            <separator/>
            <filter string="Fecha de Vencimiento" name="type_date" domain="[(1,'=',1)]" help="..."/>
            <separator/>
            <group expand="0" string="Group By...">
                <filter string="Assigned to" domain="[]" context="{'group_by' : 'user_id'}" />
                <filter string="Status" domain="[]" context="{'group_by': 'state'}"/>
                <filter string="Priority" domain="[]" context="{'group_by': 'priority'}"/>
            </group>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="module_class_act" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">xxx</field>
    <field name="res_model">module.class</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="context">{"search_default_type_date":1}</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="module_class_tree-view"/>
</record>
```

I left the group entries in so you could see what they look like, but you'll need to either remove them or adjust them so they match your data.  Also, the words `module` and `class` should be replaced with your data.

Comment: Thank you, it almost works, i mean if i use only the first xml record it shows me the field in filter options, but if i use the 2nd record along with the first ie: "module_class_act" i don't understand what should i put in "ref=module_class_tree-view" it throws me an error about an external identifier not defined in the system, i put "solvencia_solvencia_tree-view" but still got this error, solvencia is the class on which i'm working this one

Comment: One question, if i just "save" a custom filter in the search, wouldn't do the same job?

Comment: @KristianKoci: Yes.  The benefit to having it in the xml file is for fresh installs.

Comment: @KristianKoci: The `ref` is referring to a previously defined view (which I didn't show -- mine was a tree view).

Answer (score 4):

[Ethan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208880/ethan-furman)

This is how i solved it, without your advice it wouldn't be possible:

```
<record id="solvencia_search" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">solvencia.solvencia.select</field>
<field name="model">solvencia.solvencia</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <search string="Solvencias">
        <field name="Fecha_de_Vence" string="Fecha de Vencimiento" filter_domain="[('Fecha_de_Vence','=',((context_today()-datetime.timedelta(days=10)).strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d')))]"/>
        <separator/>
        <filter string="Fecha de Vencimiento" name="type_date" domain="[('Fecha_de_Vence','=',((context_today()-datetime.timedelta(days=10)).strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d')))]" help="..."/>
        <separator/>
        <group expand="0" string="Group By...">
            <filter string="Assigned to" domain="[]" context="{'group_by' : 'Fecha_de_Vence'}" />
            <filter string="Status" domain="[]" context="{'group_by': 'Fecha_de_Emision'}"/>
            <filter string="Priority" domain="[]" context="{'group_by': 'nsol'}"/>
        </group>
    </search>
</field>
```

And the `context` in `act_window`:

```
<record id="action_solvencia_solvencia" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Solvencias</field>
    <field name="res_model">solvencia.solvencia</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="context">{"search_default_type_date":1}</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="solvencia_solvencia_tree"/>
        <field name="nsol" />
        <field name="Fecha_de_Emision" />
        <field name="Fecha_de_Vence" />
        <field name="ministerio" />
        <field name="ins_em" />
        <field name="cod_ver" />
        <field name="cadidate" />
        <field name="observa" />
</record>
```

Works perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome!  You might want to change the filter strings from "Assigned to", "Status", and "Priority" to something that makes sense, though. ;)

Comment: Yeah lol hehe i'm cleaning it up, but the important things are  working now, thanks! :)